# When writing csv from CF to bucket: 'with open(filepath, "w") as MY_CSV:' leads to "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, filesystems, google-cloud-functions

I get this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` when I try to write a csv file to the bucket, using a csv writer that loops over batches of data. The full insight into the Cloud Function logs around that error:

> ````
> File "/workspace/main.py", line 299, in write_to_csv_file with
> open(filepath, "w") as outcsv: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: 'gs://MY_BUCKET/MY_CSV.csv'
>
> Function execution took 52655 ms, finished with status: 'crash' 
>
> OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this
> system, assuming 256k  ```
> ````

And this, although this bucket_filepath definitely exists: I can upload an empty dummy file and get its "gsutils URI" (right-click on the three dots at the right side of the file) and the bucket_filepath will look the same: `'gs://MY_BUCKET/MY_CSV.csv'`.

I checked saving a dummy pandas dataframe instead using `pd.to_csv` and it worked with the same bucket_filepath (!).

Therefore, there must be another reason, likely the writer is not accepted, or the `with statement` that opens the file.

The code that throws the error is as follows. It is with the same code working outside of Google Cloud Function in a normal cron job on a local server. I have added two debug prints around the line that throws the error, the `print("Right after opening the file ...")` does not show up anymore. The subfunction `query_execute_batch()` that `write_to_csv_file()` is calling for each batch is also shown but likely not the problem here since the error happens already at the very start when write-opening the csv file.

`requirements.txt` (which are then imported as modules):

```
SQLAlchemy>=1.4.2
google-cloud-storage>=1.16.1
mysqlclient==2.1.0
pandas==1.2.3
fsspec==2021.11.1
gcsfs==2021.11.1
unicodecsv==0.14.1
```

And from the `main.py`:

```python
def query_execute_batch(connection):
    """Function for reading data from the query result into batches
    :yield: each result in a loop is a batch of the query result
    """
    results = execute_select_batch(connection, SQL_QUERY)
    print(f"len(results): {len(results)}")
    for result in results:
        yield result

def write_to_csv_file(connection, filepath):
    """Write the data in a loop over batches into a csv.
    This is done in batches since the query from the database is huge.
    :param connection: mysqldb connection to DB
    :param filepath: path to csv file to write data
    returns: metadata on rows and time
    """
    countrows = 0
    print("Right before opening the file ...")    
    with open(filepath, "w") as outcsv:
        print("Right after opening the file ...")        
        writer = csv.DictWriter(
            outcsv,
            fieldnames=FIELDNAMES,
            extrasaction="ignore",
            delimiter="|",
            lineterminator="\n",
        )
        # write header according to fieldnames
        writer.writeheader()

        for batch in query_execute_batch(connection):
            writer.writerows(batch)
            countrows += len(batch)
        datetime_now_save = datetime.now()
    return countrows, datetime_now_save
```

Mind that for the above script to work, I import `gcsfs` which makes the bucket read-write-available. Else I would likely need a google cloud storage object like for example:

```python
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
```

and then make the file in that bucket with further functions, but that is not the aim here.

In the following, the `pd.to_csv` code that works, it uses the output of a dummy SQL query `SELECT 1` as the input of a dataframe. This *can* be saved to the same bucket_filepath, of course the reason might not just be `pd.to_csv()` as such, but also that the dataset is a dummy instead of complex unicode strings from a huge `SELECT query`. Or there is another reason, I am just guessing.

```python
if records is not None:
    df = pd.DataFrame(records.fetchall())
    df.columns = records.keys()
    df.to_csv(filepath,
        index=False,
    )
    datetime_now_save = datetime.now()
    countrows = df.shape[0]
```

I would like to use the csv writer to have the chance to write in unicode with the unicodecsv module and the chance to use the batches.

I might be willing to change to batches (`loop + append` mode or `chunksize`) in pandas like in [Writing large Pandas Dataframes to CSV file in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531195/writing-large-pandas-dataframes-to-csv-file-in-chunks) to get rid of this bucket filepath problem, but I would like to rather use the ready code (never touch a running system).

How can I get the saving of that csv done with the csv writer so that it can open a new file in the bucket in `write` mode = `with open(filepath, "w") as outcsv:`?

The given function `write_to_csv_file()` is just a tiny part of the Cloud Function which uses a wide range of functions and cascaded functions. I cannot show the whole reproducible case here and hope that it can be answered by experience or easier examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is surprising. You *must* import and use the `gcsfs` module if you want to write to a file with `open()`.

*If you use `pd.to_csv()`, `import gcsfs` is not needed, but **`gcsfs` is still needed in the `requirements.txt` to make `pd.to_csv()` work**, thus, pandas `to_csv()` seems to use it automatically.*

The `pd.to_csv()` surprise put aside, here is the code that answers the question (tested):

```python
def write_to_csv_file(connection, filepath):
    """Write the QUERY result in a loop over batches into a csv.
    This is done in batches since the query from the database is huge.
    :param connection: mysqldb connection to DB
    :param filepath: path to csv file to write data
    return: metadata on rows and time
    """
    countrows = 0
    print("Right before opening the file ...")
   

    # A gcsfs object is needed to open a file.
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805016/how-to-open-a-file-from-google-cloud-storage-into-a-cloud-function
    # https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#examples
    # Side-note (Exception):
    # pd.to_csv() needs neither the gcsfs object, nor its import.
    # It is not used here, but it has been tested with examples.
    fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=MY_PROJECT)
    fs.ls(BUCKET_NAME)


    # wb needed, else "builtins.TypeError: must be str, not bytes"
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512811/builtins-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes
    with fs.open(filepath, 'wb') as outcsv:
        print("Right after opening the file ...")

        writer = csv.DictWriter(
            outcsv,
            fieldnames=FIELDNAMES,
            extrasaction="ignore",
            delimiter="|",
            lineterminator="\n",
        )
        # write header according to fieldnames
        print("before writer.writeheader()")
        writer.writeheader()
        print("after writer.writeheader()")

        for batch in query_execute_batch(connection):
            writer.writerows(batch)
            countrows += len(batch)
        datetime_now_save = datetime.now()
    return countrows, datetime_now_save
```

##### Side-note

**Do not use the csv writer like this.**

It takes too long, instead of the `pd.to_csv()` with a `chunksize` parameter of 5000 which needs just 62s for the 700k rows to be loaded and stored as a csv in the bucket, the CF with the writer of batches takes more than the 9 minutes which is over the timeout limit. I am
therefore forced to use `pd.to_csv()` instead and convert my data into a dataframe for that.